# Dont Understand Thread XCode

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I get a thread here at [[c textLabel] setText:item];. I dont understand what I need to change in order to allow my app to run. The Thread says: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT. I can post more information if it is need please help.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [tasks count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
UITableViewCell *c= [taskTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

if (!c) {
    c = [[ UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

NSString *item = [tasks objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
[[c textLabel] setText:item];

return c;

}
```

Comment: Please include the full text of the crash. Probably, `item` is not a NSString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line :-

```
UITableViewCell *c= [taskTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

`taskTable` should be replaced by `tableView`(pointing to delegate method of tableView and not tableView Directly.)

Comment: I did just that and got the same thread in the same exact area.

Comment: see that you are not accessing any object without actually assigning memory to it.

Comment: Also implement the tableview delegates UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDatasource in the interface file and in the viewDidLoad set it to self..(if it is not a uiTableViewController and simply a UITableView)..Also see that you have connected the outlets if you are using xib

Comment: @roronoazorro `SIGABRT` indicates an exception, bad memory access usually ends in `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Comment: @JustSid sigbart occurs at times when the delegate methods control are not set and the properties are set on it or it being used..

Comment: @roronoazorro Then it wouldn't crash at `[[c textLabel] setText:item];`

Answer (score 0):

Try check a warnings. Usually in XCode a warnings says a more errors.

I think, error in "c" value.

Comment: @user1438042: it is an error - you're getting SIGABRT. As for definition of thread: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29

Comment: Send all your warnings from this class pls